# Update frequency of BASE open-access repository?

Tags: open-access

How often does the BASE ([Bielefeld Academic Search Engine](https://www.base-search.net/)) recrawl the considered open-access repositories?

Answer (score 2):

> Usually, all sources are updated twice a month. Records that are marked as "updated" in the OAI-PMH interface of the source, will be re-harvested and re-indexed.

Private communication from BASE team